# how to add tmp directory to amazon ses email in bash script?

Tags: bash, email, email-attachments, amazon-ses

I have a temp directory containing two files

```
#Creating a temporary directory to figure out the size
tmpSizeDir=`mktemp -d`/
trap "rm -rf $tmpSizeDir" EXIT
cp -vf "${DIRECTORY}${FILE_NAME}.csv" $tmpSizeDir
cp -vf "${DIRECTORY}${FILE_NAME}.PDF" $tmpSizeDir
```

I also have code to send an amazon ses email

```
echo "{ \"Subject\": { \"Data\": \"$subject\", \"Charset\": \"UTF-8\"}, \"Body\": { \"Text\": { \"Data\": \"$body\", #\"Charset\": \"UTF-8\" } } }" > message.json

aws ses send-email --from $MAIL_SENDER --recipient file://tmpDestinationDir --message file://message.json
```

How do I add a directory as an attachment to an amazon ses email?

Answer (score 1):

To do it: firstly you have to change the method that you are using.
`aws ses send-email` is not suited for attachments. If you want to use attachments, you have to use send-raw-email.

Here is the documentation for the CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ses/send-raw-email.html

To send a directory: firstly create a zip archive, then convert the zip archive to base64 and add it to the content of the email. Afterwards, the rest in your case stays almost the same. The one thing that you have to take into account is that in sending the raw emails you are providing by yourself all of the headers, values etc, so you will have to convert your message a bit.

Comment: There are many examples of how to assemble a MIME email message from a shell script, but unfortunately, many of them are also broken or brittle. I would suggest that you use a MIME-aware tool to create the message if you can. Traditionally that was `metamail` but it's no longer supported. These days if you can't use something like `mutt` maybe write a simple script in Python (or Ruby or whatever is convenient). One possible starting point: the [examples from the Python `email` module documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: @tripleee I was actually able to use ses in a bash script to send a csv

Comment: Yes yes, it can certainly be done; several of my answers demonstrate this; but you have to know what you are doing.

Comment: @tripleee I don't know what I'm doing :)